# How to store a dictionary [String:[Object]]?

Tags: ios, swift, nscoding

So I have a class called Restaurant and a [String:[Restaurant]] dictionary. How should I properly store this dictionary so that data inside it wouldn't be lost after user relaunches the app?

```
class Restaurant {
    var name: String?
    init?(name: String) {
        guard !name.isEmpty else {
            return nil
        }
        self.name = name
    }
}
```

---

```
var restaurants = [String: [Restaurant]]()
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // ...
    restaurants["Pizza"] = ...
}
```

Comment: You have basically two options. 1) Make your class or structure conform to Codable and write the json data to disk 2) Make your class inherit from NSObject, conform to NSCoding and use NSKeyedArchiever to convert your object to property list data and write it disk.

Comment: Apart from what @LeoDabus said, is there a particular reason for story the restaurants as dictionary with key representing the type of restaurant. You can have a property on Restaurant which can indicate the category of the restaurant.

Comment: Or you could use the `Coding` protocol to convert to either JSON or a property list.

Comment: Do you have any relevant examples of using this? All I could find is technical overviews of this classes and some guides which do not directly correspond to this topic.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [realm.io](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/)

If you want to conform both decodable and the realm object to create the object in disk you could do it as follow

```
import RealmSwift

class Restaurant: Object, Decodable {
  @objc dynamic var name: String?

  private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey { case name}

  convenience init( name: String?){
      self.init()
      self.name = name
  }

  convenience required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
      self.init()
      let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
      self.name = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .name)
  }
}

func saveToDisk(){
  let realm = try! Realm()
  try! realm.write {
      realm.add(restaurant)
  }
}
```

You can adapt it to save an array of Restaurant Object

You can use other different methods as:

```
  CoreData

  Using a file 

  UserDefaults(too slow and not for large amount of data)
```